# Copy input on keyup to similar elements

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to copy input value on keyup to other identical input fields, so that they all contain the same value real-time.
So basically I want to copy the current typed value to the other inputs. I can't make it work, though:

I have this html:

```
<input type="search" class="phrase" placeholder="Search">
<input type="search" class="phrase" placeholder="Search">
<input type="search" class="phrase" placeholder="Search">
```

and this js:

```
getPhrase = () => {
  const phrase = document.querySelectorAll('.phrase');
  let input;

  for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    phrase[i].addEventListener('keyup', () => {
      input = phrase[i].value;
      console.log(input);
    });
  }
}

getPhrase();
```

I tried to add:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    phrase[i].addEventListener('keyup', () => {
      input = phrase[i].value;
      console.log(input);
    });
    phrase.value = input // <-- This won't work.
  }
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/f0zLt3hq/).
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand it correctly, but if you want to copy the value to the other fields, then:

```
getPhrase = () => {
  const phrase = document.querySelectorAll('.phrase');
  let input;

  for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    phrase[i].addEventListener('keyup', () => {
      input = phrase[i].value;
      console.log(input);
      // loop thru the phrase's and give them value
      for (let j = 0; j < phrase.length; j++) {
        phrase[j].value = input;      
      }
    });
  }
}

getPhrase();
```

This way you are able to modify any search value from any search fields.

Comment: Works the best. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

hi Kindly use the below code I think it will work for you

```
getPhrase = () => {
  const phrase = document.querySelectorAll('.phrase');
  let input;
  phrase[0].addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
      phrase[i].value = e.target.value
      console.log(input);
     } });
}

getPhrase();
```